# Binary file on Linux machine looking for libraries in /lib by default

Tags: linux, unix

On my UNIX machine I observed that the binaries are looking for the dependent shared libraries in '`/lib`' directory by default even though the '/lib' directory is not configured in '`PATH`' and '`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`' variables.

I the below see that the library '`libssl.so.4`' is found from the '`/lib`' directory.

```
bash-3.00$ ldd openssl
        /lib/libcwait.so (0x00f86000)
        libssl.so.4 => /lib/libssl.so.4 (0x00408000)
```

My 'PATH' and 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' are below:

```
bash-3.00$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client32/lib:

bash-3.00$ echo $PATH
/opt/pure/releases/purify.hp.2003a.06.15.FixPack.0214/cache/opt/star-ncf-prod/ep_patch/usr/lib:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/etc:/bin:.:/opt/ccm71/bin:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client32/bin:/opt/tools/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Please let mw know if the binaries refer to '/lib' directory by default ?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries (on Linux OS) are searching in paths from `/etc/ld.so.conf` (not from $PATH) . After changing this file you must run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

You can see library search paths by command:

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
```

Default paths: In the default path `/lib`, and then `/usr/lib`. [The Linux loader and how it finds libraries](http://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/).